# User input help in VSCODE

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

I'm new to programming and trying to learn lua.
Issue is I can't seem to get user input to work in the debug console.
I have a very simple program that should just print whatever you enter into the console back to the console.

```
local ans = io.read() 
print(ans)
```

whenever i try to write something in the console it just returns in red 'please pause to eveluate expressions'
What does that mean and how to fix please thanks!